# Remove duplicate value in a line SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext

I couldn't find anything specifically related to removing duplicate values within a line, in a file with 1600+ lines. Does a script or plugin exist to simply the process of removing the duplicate values after s( ?

```
s(-1025,1025,{32047, 32048, 32049, 32050, 32051, 32807, 32795},128)
s(1151,1151,{8197, 8176, 8193, 8192, 8175, 31563, 9428, 94044},nil)  
s(-1012,1012,{90339, 90348, 90366, 47829, 47074, 47153, 47191},nil)
s(-1013,1013,{47686, 90352, 90370, 47616, 47068, 47744, 46991, 47087},nil)
s(-1014,1014,{90290, 90296, 90305, 90314, 47901, 47442, 47472},nil)
s(-1015,1015,{47687, 90300, 90309, 90318, 47860, 47441, 47893, 47426},nil)
s(-1016,1016,{31375, 31376, 31377, 31378, 31379, 31596, 31597},1024)
s(-1017,1017,{31987, 31988, 31989, 31990, 31991, 32798, 32786},1024)
s(-1018,1018,{33690, 33691, 33692, 33693, 33694, 33879, 33880},1024)
s(-1019,1019,{35022, 35023, 35024, 35025, 35026, 35152, 35137},1544)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just find duplicate lines then the Highlight Duplicates plugin is the way to go:

https://github.com/qur2/HighlightDuplicates

If you are looking to find duplicates within lines then I would suggest that you use pattern matching via a regular expression within the find and replace function (ctrl+h). click the `*` button to put it into regex mode and enter the appropriate. a lot of information on regular expression in sublime text can be found here:

http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html